# Alternative to keyword mutable for member variables in C++

Tags: c++, constants, mutable

I have a const function in C++, from where I am calling a C function.

```
class ClassEx
{
  A* pPointer // declaration of the pointer

};

void
ClassEx::ClassFunction() const
{

     int error = AFunctionInExternLib(&pPointer); //pPointer will be instantiated by this function.
}

//Signature of AFunctionInExternLib 
Struct A
{
};

AFunctionInExternLib(A** pPointer);
```

Now, I have a member variable for classEx of type struct A.
Since  Class::ClassFunction() is a const function I cannot pass pPointer as it is. so I made the declaration as

```
class ClassEx
{
   mutable A* pPointer // declaration of the pointer

};
```

This Compiles fine, But I was wondering if there is any other way to achieve this without using mutable keyword?

Please note I tried this also,

```
 void
 ClassEx::ClassFunction() const
 {
    A* pAnotherPointer = const_cast<A*>(pPointer);// remove constness

    int error = AFunctionInExternLib(&pAnotherPointer);
 }
```

But this would instantiate pAnotherPointer and not pPointer. Is there anyway to share address of pAnotherPointer to pPointer?

Is there any problem in this approach.

```
class ClassEx
{
  A* pPointer // declaration of the pointer

};

void
ClassEx::ClassFunction() const
{

   ClassEx* pTempPointer = const_cast<ClassEx*>(this);  
   int error = AFunctionInExternLib(&pTempPointer->pPointer); 
}
```

Comment: Make `ClassEx::ClassFunction` non-`const`? Although I cannot see how `pPointer` will be modified by the external function, since you are passing it by value.

Comment: oh, Allow me to edit this.

Comment: ClassEx::ClassFunction, this cant be made non-const.

Comment: Did you try compiling the original version? You are not modifying `pPointer`, so I see no reason for it not to compile.

Comment: with mutable its compiling, without that its not.

Comment: This is interesting.  So am I to understand that you are creating an object of type `A` using function `AFunctionInExternLib()` and you want this done in a `const` member function called `ClassEx::ClassFunction()`?  May I ask why?  This smells like it could be that this could be achieved in another way.  Mutable should only be used when the logical state doesn't change, even if the physical state (the pointer member variable) does.  Is that what you are doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible scenarios:

1. `pPointer` contributes to the observable (or logical) state of the `ClassEx` object. In such case, `ClassFunction` modifies the observable state of the object and should therefore **not** be `const`.
2. `pPointer` is an implementation detail which does no affect observable state (such as an internal cache). In such case, `mutable` is the correct tool to use. Also note that as per C++11 thread-safety rules, `mutable` members should be thread-safe; that is, they should be `atomic` or protected by a mutex.

Comment: Hi Angew:Thanks for your reply. Can you please tell me why it needs to be thread safe and how to do it?

Comment: @Yogi If you have the time, watch [Herb Sutter's excellent talk](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/C-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-You-dont-know-blank-and-blank) on the subject. *TL;DW:* the standard library now expects `const` operations to be thread safe, so if you use your class in any interaction with the std. library, you must comply. The usual approach to mutable members is to protect them by a mutex. Details on doing this are around the 20' mark in the talk.

Answer (score 0):

> Alternative to keyword mutable for member variables in C++

If there was an alternative to `mutable`, then we wouldn't need the keyword.

`A* pAnotherPointer = const_cast<A*>(pPointer);` - This is just removing the constness from a pointer, allowing you to call const methods on an object. The address is the same.

The best (as juanchopanza suggested) is to make `ClassEx::ClassFunction()` non-const.

Comment: Hi, when I tried debugging, it was showing 0X00 for pPointer. Is there any harm in using mutable?